# Produce at California borders

Tags: driving, food-and-drink, california, prohibited-items

We are traveling from Arizona to California with fresh produce.  What items might we expect to have to throw away at the border?

Comment: I think this is for shippers/growers thus not adding it to David's answer but check out [this pdf chart](https://www.cdfa.ca.gov/plant/factsheets/BringingFruitsVeggies_to_CA.pdf). Basically, all citrus, and some surprising to me stone fruit, nuts, and vegetables.

Answer (score 1):

[This California government page](https://www.cdfa.ca.gov/plant/PE/ExteriorExclusion/borders_faq.html) discusses border inspections.

The page says:

WHAT ARE YOUR INSPECTORS LOOKING FOR?

Our inspectors check vehicles and commodities for compliance with California and federal plant quarantine regulations. They also check commodities to make sure they are free from exotic invasive species that may be hitchhiking with them. Although the primary focus is on plant materials (i.e., fruits, vegetables, nursery stock, hay, firewood, etc.), other items are also frequently inspected.

Briefly, you're advised to:

Have all plant material—including fruits, vegetables, plants, hay,
       and firewood—packed for easy access.

Ensure the driver knows what is
       in the vehicle and where it is packed.

Ensure the driver has keys or
       knows the combination for all door locks.

Ensure all doors
       (especially those of self-mover trucks and trailers) can be easily
       opened and closed.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question? Having produce packed for easy access does not answer what you are allowed to bring.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll amend the Answer to include more info.

Comment: I must honestly say, that I can still not read any real answer in your text. OP is obviously aware that whatever she brings into California must be compliant with the regulations. You answering that the items must be compliant with the regulations does not solve the problem. The question is rather what these regulations say, not that there are regulations.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo If they look, it's for fruits and vegetables. If one follows the links, there are pages and pages and pages of discussion of what kind of fruits and vegetables, and what kind of process (if any) they're been subject to, and where they're from, and what kinds of pests are involved...and it is way too long and complicated for this site. You are technically correct that "fruits and vegetables" provides little info, but the reality here is that one must spend hours decoding the various health and plant departments' ideas, or just accept "fruits and vegetables." I accept it. YMMV.

Comment: What is wrong with the document mkennedy links to in his comment? I am not familiar with restrictions on produce when travelling between the different US states, but to me, it seems to give a comprehensible and extensive answer to the question.

Comment: Nothing at all, it is great response. I upvoted (the little triangle) as soon as I saw it this morning. It's 11 pages long, and would take one hours and hours to create. That's more time than I was willing to spend.

Comment: @David you wouldn't have had to spend any time to create that chart; it is from the California Department of Food and Agriculture.

Comment: True, 'tho it didn't appear immediately when I searched. The chart isn't complete, however, as it doesn't address the other sorts of stuff (soil, plant bedding material, firewood, hay) the inspectors might look for. My "it'd take too much time" reflected not finding the chart, and, when it was presented, not seeing the other stuff listed.